# What's the iOS BLE scanning behavior in background with screen locked?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to figure out what happens when scanning in background with screen locked. After screen gets locked I've noticed increasing time-span between scan periods:

- 15s
- 30s
- 1m
- 2m
- 4m

After some  time in background it seems these scan periods start to happen at random, sometimes 4m, sometimes 2m, etc.

Is there any documentation for this and whether it's possible to limit this interval?

Comment: How are you determining this?

Comment: @MarcusAdams monitoring connection/reading from another device.

Comment: Scanning in the background is passive. When scanning in the background, it won't be requesting a scan response (at least not every time). Don't see how you could detect the interval externally.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Device advertises at the fixed short rate, accept connections, notifies characteristic's change. iPhone scans,  connect to device while stopping scanning, get notified, read characteristic, close connection and start scanning again.

Comment: I am not aware of any controls over how iOS scans in the background.

Comment: Got any clue about this??

Comment: @Cookie I stopped working on that, what's detailed here and in comments is how far I've gone at the time.